# Failed NetSuite RESTlet authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, netsuite

I'm trying to develop in NetSuite a simple form portlet submitting to a RESTlet in the back end. Here's my form portlet:

```
function workManagerPortlet(portlet, column) {

    portlet.setTitle('Portlet');

    portlet.addField(....)
    // INSERT HERE ALL THE FORM FIELDS

    portlet.setSubmitButton(nlapiResolveURL('RESTLET', 'customscript_gw_ss_form_backend', 'customdeploy_wm_form_backend', true), 'Submit', '_hidden');
}
```

When I click on submit I can see in Chrome's developer console the status is **206 Partial Content**, but the record I'm submitting is not being stored in the database and in the console there's no response for this request.

Therefore, I decided to investigate the connection to the RESTlet. My problem is that I cannot get past the RESTlet authentication. Here are my NLAuth headers:

> User-Agent: SuiteScript-Call
>  Authorization: NLAuth
>  nlauth_account:
>   TSTDRV1291212
>  nlauth_email: $email
>  nlauth_signature: $password
>   nlauth_role: administrator
>  Content-Type: application/json

Obviously, replacing '$email' and '$password' for the corresponding values.

The 'nlauth_role' value is the role id in Netsuite.

I'm using Postman to test this and I always get a "**401 Authorization Required**" status and the following error.

> {
>    "error":
>  {
>       "code": "USER_ERROR",
>       "message": "header is not NLAuth scheme [ NLAuth ]"
>  }
>  }

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: nlauth values should be comma separated like this `NLAuth
nlauth_account: TSTDRV1291212, nlauth_email: $email, nlauth_signature: $password, nlauth_role: administrator`.

Comment: one more thing, trying sending `3` instead of `administrator`. It's role id actually which is required by NetSuite.

Comment: Thank you @ZainShaikh for pointing me in the right direction. I fixed it using the headers `Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRV1291212, nlauth_email=$email, nlauth_signature=$password, nlauth_role=3`

Comment: that's good. let me post it as answer, so you could accept it as answered :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nlauth values should be comma separated like this:

```
NLAuth nlauth_account: TSTDRV1291212, nlauth_email: $email, nlauth_signature: $password, nlauth_role: administrator`
```

One more thing, trying sending `3` instead of `administrator`. It's role id actually which is required by NetSuite.

Comment: in case someone has trouble with the above, I had to change the syntax to this: `NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRV1291212, nlauth_email=$email, nlauth_signature=$pass, nlauth_role=3`